# Dynamically creating bindings at object creation time - possible?

Tags: javascript, ember.js

Is it possible to dynamically create a binding?  Say I have an object called 'App.obj' with 2 properties 'alpha' and 'beta', and I want to use it with the same view in 2 places:

```
{{view App.AView name="alpha"}}
```

and

```
{{view App.AView name="beta"}}
```

The view is meant to bind to either the 'alpha' or 'beta' property of App.obj depending on what its name property is set to, such that when the bound-to property changes, so does the view.  So the whole point of the exercise here is that, given two very similar properties on an object, can I create just a single view that will bind to either of them, and update itself when that property changes.

Is it possible to make the view object bind to either alpha or beta on App.obj dynamically based on what is passed into it with 'name' at creation time?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Why don't you just do `{{view App.AView name="alpha" objBinding="App.obj"}}` and then in your definition of App.AView:

```
App.AView = Ember.View.extend({

didInsertElement: function() {
    var name = this.get('name');
    var objAlpha = this.getPath('obj.alpha');
    var objBeta = this.getPath('obj.beta');

    if(name == 'alpha') {
        console.log(objAlpha);
    } else if (name == 'beta') {
        console.log(objBeta);
    }
}
});
```

I have a full example in [this jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ud3323/CCAbA/). Just look at your console.

Comment: Well the point is that if the view should bind to the alpha or beta property of the object, so when that changes, so does the view.  This would just use the value of the property as it was when the view was created, right?  I should really clarify this in the original question...

Comment: So you have an object `App.obj` with properties `.alpha` and `.beta` and you want to have `App.getPath('obj.alpha')` to be bound to a view defined as `{{view App.AView name="alpha"}}`? So `App.getPath('obj.alpha')` would return an the above mentioned Ember.View instance? If so, I'd have some major questions about your design... In your clarification can you be more specific about exactly what problem you're trying to solve? Code example would help greatly. Fork the jsFiddle I have above and modify it to demonstrate whatever problem you're having. I'll be more than happy to take a look :)

Comment: I just pressed ctrl-r instead of ctrl-s in the jsfiddle, and lost all my work.  I can't be bothered to redo it right now, so I'm just going to add every property on the object to the list of dependencies on the view's computed property, hence solving my problem - how to make 1 view that looks exactly the same, but serves a different property of an object based on a configurable parameter.